# how to change saxon param=values

Tags: saxon

SAXON 6.5.4 from Michael Kay
Usage:  java com.icl.saxon.StyleSheet [options] source-doc style-doc **{param=value}...**
Options:
  -a              Use xml-stylesheet PI, not style-doc argument
  -ds             Use standard tree data structure
  -dt             Use tinytree data structure (default)
  -o filename     Send output to named file or directory
  -m classname    Use specified Emitter class for xsl:message output
  -r classname    Use specified URIResolver class
  -t              Display version and timing information
  -T              Set standard TraceListener
  -TL classname   Set a specific TraceListener
  -u              Names are URLs not filenames
  -w0             Recover silently from recoverable errors
  -w1             Report recoverable errors and continue (default)
  -w2             Treat recoverable errors as fatal
  -x classname    Use specified SAX parser for source file
  -y classname    Use specified SAX parser for stylesheet
  -?              Display this message

Answer (score 0):

If your stylesheet declares a parameter

```
<xsl:param name="iridescent"/>
```

Then you can set it from the command line with (for example)

```
java com.icl.saxon.Stylesheet source.xml style.xsl iridescent=no
```

Comment: You can pass any string you like. But you're just passing a parameter to your stylesheet code, Saxon isn't going to do anything with it other than make it available as the value of a variable/parameter, e.g `$iridescent`